# Fastest Bitwise Operation in C#

Tags: c#, performance, bit-manipulation

Is any particular bitwise operation (AND, OR, XOR, etc.) faster than another in C#?

The reason I ask is because I know that in hardware, most things are built using NAND gates, because a few NAND gates can replicate any other gate.  Does this have any ramifications on high level programming languages?  Or do all the abstraction layers in between make it so they all run at the same speed.

I realize any performance boost gained from this would be minimal, I'm just asking out of curiosity.

EDIT: Please, stop trying to explain that there is not functional reason to know this.  It's literally just curiosity.

However, I am generating a HashCode by performing some bitwise operation on two numbers.  It makes sense to use the least expensive/fastest operation possible.  Again, it won't make any difference, I'm just curious.

EDIT: My question boils down to this: Does the fact that hardware depends on NAND gates at the lower levels have any effect on higher level processes.  Would this cause a NAND to be faster than an XOR?

I ask out of curiosity about how details of hardware can impact software.  It's just interesting to me.

Comment: The performance boost is not minimal, it is infinitesimally small. Also, Code quality > Code optimization where clearly not needed.

Comment: Even if you weren't so many layers above the hardware that it's meaningless, .NET code runs on a variety of different processors (and even architectures) so there wouldn't be a single answer for C#.

Comment: it doesn't matter, I just like understanding

Comment: No one is stopping you from trying to write your own benchmarks to suss this out, it's just really hard to answer in a meaningful way because it may differ across platforms and runtimes.

Comment: Not to try to extend this much further - the best way to write high performance code is first to set performance *goals*, and then to write the most straight forward method you can think of to achieve the functionality. Then you *measure* the performance, and then, if it's not acceptable, you profile the code to determine where to focus your efforts - or even discover that your algorithm is working at the wrong order of complexity. You don't write high performance code by micro-analysing each possible alternative at each step and trying to combine them.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm not trying to write high performance code, I just want to learn something... It's like studying the background of a video game character.  Does it improve you in any way?  No, its just interesting to me.

Comment: Paraphrasing a bit "I want to know the fastest possible operation" and "I'm not trying to write high performance code" are two statements in conflict with each other.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Is it conflicting to ask "What profession makes the most money?" and say "I'm not interested in making the most money."?  What is so confusing about me just being curious.

Comment: It is if you're on a website where we try to help people solve practical problems, rather than to help them learn answers to trivia questions that will not be of any benefit if (at any short time in the future) the answers given are no longer accurate.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If you're arguing about the fact that my question belongs on a different site thats something different.  It does not discount the validity of my question.

Comment: I'm more in despair that you seem to believe that there's any redeeming value in learning things that may no longer be accurate by the time you've read the answer. Most people, in transitioning from childhood to adulthood get to a point where they realise that memorising rote facts is less useful than acquiring the means to experiment for themselves (and also to learn that their own experience won't necessarily by the same as others)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Why do some people learn klingon?  It's interesting to learn how things work.  I am sorry that you don't share my desire to learn things, but please don't pity me for taking joy in the details.

Comment: I wouldn't pity anyone for learning Klingon (I think). I would pity someone trying to learn Klingon if their stated aim was to improve their communication skills (in general).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm not trying to improve programming.  Once again, I'm literally just curious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is any particular bitwise operation (AND, OR, XOR, etc.) faster than another in C#?

I've created a benchmark:

```
Random r = new Random();
int a = r.Next();
int b = r.Next();
int c = 0;
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

sw.Start();
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    c += a & b;
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("AND operator: {0} ticks", sw.Elapsed.Ticks);
Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", c);
c = 0;
// The above is just to make sure that the optimizer does not optimize the loop away,
// as pointed out by johnnycrash in the comments.
sw.Restart();
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    c += a | b;
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("OR operator: {0} ticks", sw.Elapsed.Ticks);
Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", c);
c = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    c += a ^ b;
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("XOR operator: {0} ticks", sw.Elapsed.Ticks);
Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", c);
c = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    c += ~a;
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("NOT operator: {0} ticks", sw.Elapsed.Ticks);
Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", c);
c = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    c += a << 1;
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Left shift operator: {0} ticks", sw.Elapsed.Ticks);
Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", c);
c = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
{
    c += a >> 1;
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine("Right shift operator: {0} ticks", sw.Elapsed.Ticks);
Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", c);
```

It outputs this:

```
AND operator: 7979680 ticks
OR operator: 7826806 ticks
XOR operator: 7826806 ticks
NOT operator: 7826806 ticks
Left shift operator: 7826806 ticks
Right shift operator: 7826806 ticks
```

The AND operator takes longer because it is the first loop. If I switch the AND and the OR loop for example, then the OR loop takes more time.

Comment: On my system, the optimizer pulls the operations out of the loop, so all that is being measured is the loop counter being incremented and tested.

Comment: Actually, since the resulting c is never used, the code being tested is entirely removed.

Comment: @johnnycrash Does it work if you disable optimizing?

Comment: It works if you add 'c' to the WrtiteLine statements and leave optimizations on.  Seems like you can add it to the first writeln and the optimizer keeps calculating c in all the loops.  The optimizer is not that impressive...  Also << 1 looks implemented with mov eax, a, add eax, eax...not using shift.

Comment: Normally when you write a loop like like you did, where you set a value to the same thing in each loop, an optimizer will get rid of the loop and do the calculation one time.  I always have to look at the disassembly and change my test to fool the optimizer.  Usually I end up accumulating the test, like c += a >> (i&31), and you always to output the calculation so it looks like the result is used.

Comment: @johnnycrash I see, I updated my answer (and added the `c` to every WriteLine just to be safe). Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Well guess what... I'm just learning c# today, and I discovered something else.  Unless you check off "tools|debug|general|suppress jit optimization on module load" then JIT does not optimize.  SO when I flipped that on, I saw the const optimization I was worried about.  So... the test still doesnt work, since the assignments are pulled out of the loops.  the weird thing is the loops are still there.  But I'm using studio 2010 and .net 4.0 and so the newer compiler could be better than that.  I think you have to change c somehow so it doesn't think its a constant.

Comment: Seems like all times are identical.  note: shl and shr also insert and 0x1F to prevent shifting too far.

Comment: Times are not identical.  I fixed a bug.  So...  I get ~=170, <<=195,  &&=127, >>=195, |=127, ^=130.  Times fluctuate, but thats the usual spread.  shl and shr are slowed down by doing an "and" with 0x1f.  So basically, aside from .net adding in more instructions to safely implement shl and shr, they are all the same speed as expected.  To fool the optimizer, I changed all the tests to q += a | i; or some variation of that so printing out q at the end forced the optimizer to keep the tests in the loop.

Comment: @johnnycrash Thanks a lot for your comments! I edited my answer with the new benchmark and the new results. The results don't really change though.

Comment: You never restarted the timer, thus you get the same results for everything after testing the OR.

Comment: @404 Nice catch! More than 5 years... so basically my answer has always been completely meaningless, and I can't even delete it because it's accepted.

Comment: This makes no sense - bit shifting should always be faster.

Answer (score 5):

CPU's are synchronous logics engine, driven by a clock. These low-level operations are all performed in a single instruction.

Comment: An OR is likely to be done in one cycle, yes, but using an OR in code is going to potentially result in loading one or two values from memory, doing the operation, and potentially storing the result back in memory.

Comment: That makes sense to me, though it's a slightly disappointing answer.  Thanks!

Comment: @Servy: in what way would this make a difference to AND or XOR ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust The fact that you're never actually doing just one of those operations; if you're measuring/comparing them you're almost certainly measuring primarily something else.

Comment: @Nealon: actually the behavior of modern processors is so complex (pipelined execution, multiple pipelines, speculative branching & execution, caching levels) that it is quasi-nondeterministic. The same instruction can have wildly varying latencies depending on context. The true improvements are achieved by ensuring good locality, avoiding data dependencies and banning the branches.

Comment: @Servy: AND/OR/XOR are equivalent instructions from the standpoint of assembly or high-level languages (same number of operands, similar use of the ALU). There is no reason they should induce a different behavior, even taking into account the loads/stores or other extras or compiler optimizations.